# check if element still has mouseenter after delay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouseevent

i made some blocks with a `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

```
<button onMouseEnter={this.MouseEnter}>hover</button>

MouseEnter(e) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        //check if mouse over still on this element 
        // do action
    }, 600);
}
```

the problem is when i move the blocks very fast the last block detects the mouseenter before the timeout and do the action even if i'm not hovering on the block which is a bug, i want to make it the action run only after `500ms` of hover on block.

p.s: i'm working with react.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The piece you're *really* missing is the invalidation of the timeout callback if the `mouseLeave` event is triggered. For this you need to hold on to the returned `setTimeout` value in order to call `clearTimeout` before the timer expires (*or if the component unmounts!!*)

The following is the basic machinery in a class-based component:

```
state = {
  hovered: false
};
timer;

mouseEnterHandler = () => this.setState({ hovered: true });
mouseLeaveHandler = () => this.setState({ hovered: false });

onTimeout = () => {
  // Do action
};

clearTimer = () => {
  clearTimeout(this.timer);
};

// Here's the meat:
// If state updates, then componentDidUpdate is called,
// if the new hovered state is true, set timeout and save the
// returned reference, else clear the timeout using the saved
// timer reference.

componentDidUpdate() {
  const { hovered } = this.state;

  if (hovered) {
    this.timer = setTimeout(this.onTimeout, 500);
  } else {
    this.clearTimer();
  }
}

// This is component cleanup, if the component unmounts before
// the timer expires you may not want the "Do action" to fire,
// so we go ahead and clear the timeout so you're not accidentally
// accessing state/props of an unmounted component.

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.clearTimer();
}
```

The following is the equivalent functional component logic:

```
const [hovered, sethovered] = useState(false);

const mouseEnterHandler = () => sethovered(true);
const mouseLeaveHandler = () => sethovered(false);

const onTimeout = () => {
  // Do action
};

useEffect(() => {
  const timer = hovered && setTimeout(onTimeout, 500);
  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  };
}, [hovered]);
```

[image: Edit pedantic-flower-wsp3z]

Comment: thanks a lot! this cleared a lot of blur on the work i'm doing.
one last thing  `timer;` should i make it `this.timer;` in `constructor(props)` ? 
i did that but that trigger an error in terminal 
`expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an experession`

Comment: @SaidBenmoumen If setting in `constructor` then you should provide an initial value, `this.timer = null;`. Updated my codesandbox demo.